# Why is my credit card not showing on my credit report?

Tags: credit-card, united-kingdom, credit-score, credit-report

I have just got my credit report. All seems fine, but I have noticed that there is no mention of my credit card on the report.

I only have one and it is with the same bank current account. I was a bit concerned because due to some administractive mixups a few months ago I missed some payments.

Why would this not be showing up on my report?

Does this mean that whatever I do with my card won't affect my credit score?

**EDIT**

Just noticed another strangeness, the Credit Card company have added a Linked Address to my report. However, the post code (zip code for Americans) is wrong. So there is an address (albeit wrong), but no payment information..

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying the account isn't showing up at all on the report, or just that the late payments didn't show up?

What could explain the account not showing up is that not all credit card companies report to all credit agencies. You have more than one credit report, it probably will show up on one of the others. The big three are Experian, TransUnion, and Equifax.

[AnnualCreditReport.com](https://www.annualcreditreport.com/cra/index.jsp) is a good starting off point to check all three easily.

Comment: The account isn't showing up at all. Strangely, I have a loan with the same bank as my credit card and that is showing up.

Comment: I have checked this with AnnualCreditReport.co.uk. I'm not sure if they are the same as the .com..

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, there is a minimum number of days under which your late payment won't show up as a bullet on your credit report.  I'm not sure if that means it won't affect your score, but it won't be there as text in black and white.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like they may have confused you with another person.  It's quite possible (or at least, it used to be) to have a credit card without the company knowing anything but your name and address, without it being linked to your social security/insurance number or whatever you have in the UK.  That's less likely since you said it's linked to your bank account, but I guess that or something similar could still happen.  Get it straightened out with your bank or the credit bureau directly.